Modifying the input triggers the listener with a value that includes the latest user input
For example, if the input is 10 and the user types 1, the detected value becomes 101, which is greater than 50. The value is then set to 50, but on the next detection, it changes to 501 instead of staying at 50.


const inputElement = document.getElementById('myInput');
console.log('The output I get is:')
inputElement.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  let value = Number(event.target.value)
  console.log("value：" + value)
  if (value > 50) {
    event.target.value = 50
    console.log("It cannot be greater than 50");
  }
});
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Type something...">



My input is:'1' -> '2' -> '3';
The output I get is:
value：1
value：1
value：12
value：12
value：123
It cannot be greater than 50
value：503
It cannot be greater than 50


Interestingly, this doesn’t seem to happen every time, but I’m not sure what triggers it.

Can you provide more of your code and specify your problem please? Its not clear from your question.

You may want to regex for numbers

addEventListener will be executed twice @RedApple

@ZVMAGL3 Only if you add it twice

It doesn't have to be triggered @mplungjan

I think it might be a browser issue because when it triggers twice, it happens on all webpages@mplungjan

i don't understand what the problem is, the code seems to work OK. That is, if I type 50 and then a 1 it sticks at 50. Could you explain more what is not working for you?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sometimes it runs normally, but in most cases, the listener runs twice when I input something. This is the problem I'm encountering.@AHaworth

This is the result of running it on this page
My input is:'1' -> '2' -> '3';
···
1
1
12
12
123
It cannot be greater than 50
503
It cannot be greater than 50
···
It listens twice every time an input is given.

This is the expected behavior, since you cannot prevent the user from typing (from the keyboard) a number or other text.
First, you read the text entered by the user, and then, if it is larger than the maximum, you change it ('501' becomes '50')

This is unexpected. I can see the feedback from console.log—it listens twice every time an input is given. When the number is 10 and the user inputs '1', the console.log output is '101' and '501'. It’s clear that it first recognizes '101' as greater than 50, then updates the value to 50. However, it recognizes the input again and adds '1'. I have checked my hardware and there is no issue with double inputs.

I have tried your snippet and done the input as you describe in your comment. The console log does NOT include 501. I am on Edge on Windows 11, what OS and browser are you using?

I’m using Google Chrome, and this problem doesn’t always occur.@AHaworth

@Alex it isn't expected behavior, and it's not the behavior I am seeing. We now know it's not always seen by OP either so maybe we are looking for a timing issue.

@AHaworth what is unexpected? read the code carefully
event listener function flow:

read input from text field.
console.log(input.value).
if input.value > 50 => input.value = 50.
it would console.log() => 50 only if OP changed value BEFORE logging it.


This is the output OP is seeing sometemes: "'1' -> '2' -> '3'; ··· 1 1 12 12 123 It cannot be greater than 50 503 It cannot be greater than 50 ··· It listens twice every time an input is given". They say it isn't consistent - it is not the expected behavior, and it is not the behavior I see when I run the code.

works fine in firefox, embedded console from console snippet also works fine.
if OP uses something else then he should look for the problem not in code, but in his browser or check other code which can duplicate event listener.
